# Showing retina display image with pure css

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, retina-display

I have a situation where I can't possibly know the dimensions of an image (a proprietary limited cms...)

I need to figure out how to show a retina level image, and I want to do so without using javascript (if possible).

I've been using:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

but that only has helped me with elements that have background images. Since the image in question can't be a background image (since I don't know the size...) what's a way of figuring this out?

I have `logo.png` and `logo2x.png`, and my applicable markup looks something like:

```
<h1 id="logo">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
  </a>
</h1>
```

Is this possible without javascript? I'm not against using non-standard css for this - as long as it works with webkit (ios/iphone in this case). I want to display `logo.png` for normal browsers but `logo2x.png` for browsers with a pixel ratio of at least 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this trick: output all images and show only relevant images to each device:

**HTML markup:**

```
<h1 id="logo">
  <a href="/">
    <img class="logo logo_normal" src="images/logo.png" />
    <img class="logo logo_retina" src="images/logo2x.png" />
  </a>
</h1>
```

**CSS styles:**

```
.logo_retina { display: none; }

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .logo_normal { display: none; }
    .logo_retina { display: block; }
}
```

Also you can use this **[‘adaptive images’](http://adaptive-images.com/)** solution and read about **[adaptive images saga](http://html5doctor.com/html5-adaptive-images-end-of-round-one/)** on html5doctor

***UPDATE:*** [**dabblet link**](http://dabblet.com/gist/4134213)

**HTML:**

```
<h1><a class="logo ir" href="/">BRAND</a></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
#logo a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('//placekitten.com/200');
}

@media  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),
        (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),
        (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:3/2),
        (min-resolution:1.5dppx) {
    #logo a {
        background: url('//placekitten.com/400');
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `logo2x.png` doesn't display at twice the density, it's just larger. It's still just as "fuzzy" as `logo.png`. At some point, I think the retina image needs to be made 50% it's width & height or something.

Comment: a big proplem with this approach is that actually both images will be loaded! `display:none` does not prevent an image from being loaded, it just won't be displayed...

Comment: Yeah, loads both images... horrible for bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Having thought about this issue myself - how about just using the x2 image and making sure to set the image's pixel dimensions? Retina displays will show it 1:1, and non-retina displays will show it at 50%. All clients have to load the x2 version though, meaning more traffic.