# Retina Display for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, retina-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing retina display image with pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958308/showing-retina-display-image-with-pure-css)

I have been doing some reading regarding retina display media queries to serve up a higher quality image for those who have retina display.. My question is do i save the same image twice in my assets (one med quality and the other high quality) for example and then serve one or the other dependent upon if the device is retina-ready

Or do i have one image and then use a media query to serve the image on a retina enabled device at its maximum quality.

My second question is how would i tell the browser to serve ALL images at the highest quality if the user has a retina enabled device

Any advice is appreciated and apologies if this is a basic question

Comment: wouldnt class this as a duplicate, doesnt answer any of my questions

Comment: @Richlewis Sounds like a duplicate though, except you haven't tagged the question identically. Why do you want to do it with jquery rather than CSS?

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you must serve different images as per device resolutions - main reason being small devices *may* have lower bandwidth connection and less resources (consider local cache) etc - so lower resolution images (having lower size) would be better alternatives.

Whether you create static assets or use some tool/handler to dynamically create them is a different question. For example, [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) is PHP based solution that takes later approach.

**EDIT**
As to your second question, if you are using media queries then browser would make that decision every time - IMO, there will not be any solution other than to say use media query to apply entire css file meant for that device. But I don't think that there would be any significant different from performance perspective.

Comment: Thanks, constructive answer and just the confirmation I needed...So theres no blanket approach to say apply retina display quality to all images

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching for some solutions on the web? Have you tried anything?

For example have you tried [Retina.js](http://retinajs.com/)?

The problem with the so called "retina" displays is that the devices browser lies to you about its resolution and scales every image and every other dimension that you have on your website. If those were just high resolution displays with no lying about it then there would be no problems like that and the [standard responsive design techniques](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/) and [responsive IMGs tricks](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-imgs-part-2/) would just work.

Unfortunately it is not the case and now your designs have to deal with:

1. the width (what is the width of the screen)
2. the device-width (what is *really* the width of the screen)
3. the device-width multiplied by the "retina" scaling factor (what is *really* **really** the width of the screen)

Comment: Retina JS looks like very good